# Inline css issues

Tags: css, inline

[image]i want to ask if its possible to fix. I have inserted pay with paypal button, but its floating to the left. I want to make it in the middle, is it possible, i could use inline css but i cant.

i have tried like that:

```html
<input type="image" src="https://mywebsite.com/img/cms/pay-try.png" style="margin-left:15px;" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
```

but no result at all, its not moving

Best regards
Dilshod

Comment: Just a suggestion: You can inspect the element with your browser then go to 'box model' tab and play with padding and margin until you get the result you want. Then add it to your code.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i tried almost everything, tried to class and adding css style, but no result.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it an a form and use `text-align: center` like

```html
<form style="text-align:center" action="#" mehod="post">
    <input type="image" src="https://mywebsite.com/img/cms/pay-try.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
</form>
```

Comment: No result at all, its not moving. Thank you for quick reply, greatly appreciated

Comment: @Dilshod What behaviour do you want, coz works fine for me, have you tried running the code snippet i have included in the post.

Comment: <input type="image" src="https://mywebsite.com/img/cms/pay-try.png"  border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <input type="image" src="https://mywebsite.com/img/cms/pay-try.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
</div>
```